# How to divide an image to blocks, process them, and merge them back together in Python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I want to divide my image into 4x4 blocks, then upscale every block, and finally merge them back together

I have consulted various ways on Stackoverflow but they do not mention how to merge blocks back together

[image]

Comment: It is not necessary to split and merge. Just work on slices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple images numpy array into blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68613829/multiple-images-numpy-array-into-blocks)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a copy paste of my answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68613829/multiple-images-numpy-array-into-blocks/68617786#68617786) with the addition of how to reassemble the images:

I would do smth like what I do in the code below. In my example I used parts of images from skimage.data to illustrate my method and made the shapes and sizes different so that it will look prettier. But you can do the same for your dta by adjusting those parameters.

```
from skimage import data
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

astronaut = data.astronaut()
coffee    = data.coffee()

arr = np.stack([coffee[:400, :400, :], astronaut[:400, :400, :]])
plt.imshow(arr[0])
plt.title('arr[0]')
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(arr[1])
plt.title('arr[1]')

arr_blocks = arr.reshape(arr.shape[0], 4, 100, 4, 100, 3, ).swapaxes(2, 3)
arr_blocks = arr_blocks.reshape(-1, 100, 100, 3)


for i, block in enumerate(arr_blocks):
    plt.figure(10+i//16, figsize = (10, 10))
    plt.subplot(4, 4, i%16+1)
    plt.imshow(block)
    plt.title(f'block {i}')

# batch_size = 9
# some_outputs_list = []
# for i in range(arr_blocks.shape[0]//batch_size + ((arr_blocks.shape[0]%batch_size) > 0)):
#     some_outputs_list.append(some_function(arr_blocks[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]))
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And for reassembling the images I would do smth like this:

```
arr_blocks = arr_blocks.reshape(-1, 4, 4, 100, 100, 3).swapaxes(2, 3)
arr_blocks = arr_blocks.reshape(-1, 400, 400, 3)

for i, block in enumerate(arr_blocks):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(block)
    plt.title('reconstruction {i}')
```

output:

[image]